# Where exactly do Chrome extension event listeners get stored?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events

When you register an event in order to load an event page, where exactly does that event registration get stored? The docs say that the event listeners only exist in the context of the event page, but that seems to contradict those listeners being used. For example:

1. My extension is installed and `runtime.onInstalled()` is called
2. In the callback for that method, I register an event with `chrome.tabs.onCreate.addListener()`.
3. I go to the kitchen to get a bag of Funyuns. By the time I get back and wipe the Funyuns dust off my hands to open a new tab, `runtime.onSuspend()` will have been called and the event page will have been unloaded
4. I open another tab and the listener is called. More importantly the listener is registered again so the background page can be loaded when I open more tabs

This seems to make sense, except when the page gets unloaded the first time, where *does* that event listener go? And if the listener was registered, then I closed the browser, then I opened a new tab, would that listener still be registered when I open the browser again (and therefore a tab is created)? And is there any way in Chrome to keep track of which event listeners are registered?

Answer (score 0):

when you sometime in admistaritor and goto your accont like c:\xyz\roaming\appdata\google than you can find your extation and also you find in cdrive google install directoriy than also search them.

Comment: Please fix your typos, and rephrase your answer